# how to compare input with two columns of a table using a single sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use only one single query to compare the given name with the two fields of database named `FirstName`, `LastName`.

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE FirstName AND LastName ='test last';
```

This query is wrong, and I would like to correct it. Can you help me?

`test` is `FirstName` and `last` is the `LastName`

Comment: What database engine are you using? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle etc.?

Comment: MySQL, wrote a comment to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE Firstname+' '+Lastname = 'test last'
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE Firstname+Lastname = 'testlast'
```

For MySQL it's:

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE CONCAT(Firstname,Lastname) = 'testlast'
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE CONCAT(Firstname,' ',Lastname) = 'test last'
```

Comment: this statment is returning the all ids from the table even for the  firstname and lastname are not 'test last'

Comment: what server are you tring on, MySQL, MSSQL,Oracle,...?

Comment: i am so surprised but its still returning all ids

Comment: Edited :D. Next time write all necessary info :)

Comment: one  thing more if i want to use this query now in an other query using IN then will it be like `SELECT id FROM admin WHERE CONCAT(Firstname,Lastname) IN (SELECT handle_by FROM task_record)`

Comment: `CONCAT(Firstname,Lastname)` expects string 'testlast' format, check if handle_by is in that format in task_record

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to get from DB with this query now, maybe post it as another question

Answer (score 1):

**(updated)**

I think you're looking for, if you're using SQL Server

```
SELECT id 
FROM admin 
WHERE FirstName + ' ' + LastName = 'test last';
```

or if you want a generic query to check all situations like this from your tables

```
SELECT id 
FROM admin 
WHERE FirstName + ' ' + LastName = CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)
```

Comment: you didnt get my question i cant afford a break that `FirstName ='test' AND LastName = 'last';`

Comment: @QadeerKhan I didn't get your question because it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: @QadeerKhan You have two columns FirstName where you have store 'test' and LastName where you have 'last'. And you want to compare BOTH of these columns with their concatenated result `test last`? Then, my friend, your query will return nothing. (this is what can be understood from your question)

Comment: is not there any way to check this with single query......i want to compare BOTH of these columns with their concatenated result test last

Comment: @QadeerKhan You should display just what data you have, and what format you want it displayed. And also, what you have tried.

Comment: how can i use this for my given case

Comment: @QadeerKhan First query is for your specific case. The second query is for any `FirstName` and `LastName`.

Comment: the firstname and lastname will be in CONCAT() ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

> select id from admin where Firstname ='test' and LastName='last'

Answer (score 0):

In Sybase it works as follows:

```
SELECT id
FROM admin
WHERE FirstName LIKE "test"
  AND LastName  LIKE "last"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
SELECT id FROM admin WHERE FirstName ='test' AND LastName = 'last';
```

You have to Use 'AND' Operator..